# How to add a trigger to lambda function via SDK or CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm trying to add a trigger to a lambda function, using the UI, I'm able to select trigger type "Cloud Watch".

[image]

Browser (Chrome) network tab, reveals this function being called.

```
fetch(
    "https://console.aws.amazon.com/lambda/services/ajax?operation=createRelation&locale=en",
    {
      headers: {
        accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
        "content-type": "application/json",
      },
      body: {
        type: "trigger",
        source: "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:7669313121:log-group:api-gateway-testAPI:*",
        target: "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:7669313121:function:datadog-ForwarderStack-SSQ7M5T3R0FL-Forwarder-ex9N3F3QIExf",
        data: '{"enabled":true,"identifier":"arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:766931360739:log-group:api-gateway-testAPI:*","filterName":"apigwLogs"}',
        operation: "createRelation",
      },
      method: "POST",
    }
  );
```

I haven't been able to find an equivalent function via SDK or CDK, I'm wondering if it's an acceptable practice to use the above function to achieve this task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to select a ClouWatch log stream as a trigger for a Lambda function, AWS creates a [subscription](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudwatchlogs.html) under the hood.

CDK supports subscriptions and destinations for log streams by creating a [`SubscriptionFilter`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-logs-readme.html#subscriptions-and-destinations).

From the JavaScript SDK (V3) you can create subscription filters using [`PutSubscriptionFilterCommand`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cloudwatch-logs/classes/putsubscriptionfiltercommand.html).

Comment: I was able to get it done via SDK and CDK, thanks for your help